# Is there a python package which does what WWW::Mechanize does in perl?

Tags: python, perl, www-mechanize

Is there a python package which can handle the same tasks covered by WWW::Mechanize in perl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about the python port of WWW::Mechanize: [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)?

Comment: @APE I'm curious: What are the Google search terms you used that _don't_ yield that package as the very first result?